# Files are missing after adding them to .gitignore and going back to an older revision

Tags: git

I have a strange situation when I remove ignore on some files from .gitignore. As an example if .gitignore include *.txt and after some time I want to add txt files to be versioned, the I remove the line *.txt from .gitignore file, then do commit.

If I try to go back to previous versions, then the *.txt files are missing!

On previous versions, the *.txt files were there, but were un-versioned. Now when I'm trying to go back, I wanted to see the old txt files, but they are missing. I have the txt files only from the version that I added them to the .gitignore.

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Git cannot revert files from before they were versioned. It simply does not record a history for them until you start committing them to a repository.

Comment: I know that, but it looks strange that the files are disappear when I go back to previous version. These files were there all the time, and now they are there only from the time I started to control their version.

Comment: When you go back to before the file was managed in git (in the history) it removes the managed file by deleting it. I can't think of any more logical behaviour. It can't keep the old unmanaged file (that would be magic). It can't leave a managed version lying around (which one would it choose, and anyway - it might break things to have an unmanaged file hanging about) The only sensible choice is to delete it.